# Writing to isolated storage in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to **read from the isolated storage if the file is exist it will delete the whole file and directories before recreating the file.**

Then if the file does not exist it will create the file and directories.

Below is my code: I got a **error of opertion not permitted on isolated storage at write file**

int indexQues;

```
    string rate;
    string[] queSplit;
    string[] rateSplit;
    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        indexQues = queListPicker.SelectedIndex;
        rate = rateListPicker.SelectedItem.ToString();

        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        try
        {
        //For question
        StreamReader readFileQue = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));
        //For passing rate
        StreamReader readFileRate = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));

        String queText = readFileQue.ReadLine();
        queSplit = queText.Split(new char[] { '^' });

        String rateText = readFileRate.ReadLine();
        rateSplit = rateText.Split(new char[] { '^' });


        readFileQue.Close();
        readFileRate.Close();

        int noOfQueInDB = queSplit.Count();
        int noOfRateInDB = rateSplit.Count();

        MessageBox.Show(noOfQueInDB.ToString());

        //if (noOfQueInDB == 2)
        //{
            myStore.DeleteFile("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt");
            myStore.DeleteFile("SettingFolder\\rateSetting.txt");
           myStore.DeleteDirectory("SettingFolder");
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted all");

            myStore.CreateDirectory("SettingFolder");

            //Retrieve the content of "noOfQues"
            //And write it into queSetting.txt
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore));
            writeFile.Write(indexQues);
            // writeFile.Write("^" + indexQues);
            writeFile.Close();

            StreamWriter writeFile1 = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\rateSetting.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore));
            writeFile1.Write(rate);
            writeFile1.Close();


            MessageBox.Show("Setting Saved");
            MessageBox.Show(indexQues.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(rate);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        //}
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            myStore.CreateDirectory("SettingFolder");

            //Retrieve the content of "noOfQues"
            //And write it into queSetting.txt

            // ****
            // **** The following line throws an exception 
            // ****
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore));
            writeFile.Write(indexQues);
            // writeFile.Write("^" + indexQues);
            writeFile.Close();

            StreamWriter writeFile1 = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\rateSetting.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore));
            writeFile1.Write(rate);
            writeFile1.Close();


            MessageBox.Show("Setting Saved");
            MessageBox.Show(indexQues.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(rate);
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

}

Comment: You can't make a code section bold. Also, do not use exceptions for control flow. The IsoLatedStorage storage API has functions for checking whether files / folders exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one point - this seems wrong (you open the same file twice ?):

```
 //For question
    StreamReader readFileQue = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));
    //For passing rate
    StreamReader readFileRate = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\queSetting.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));
```

second point - you should use Dispose:

```
    readFileQue.Close(); readFileQue.Dispose(); readFileQue = null;
    readFileRate.Close(); readFileRate.Dispose(); readFileRate = null;
```

third point - user proper FileAccess when creating the files:

```
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("SettingFolder\\rateSetting.txt",
                        FileMode.Create,
                        FileAccess.Write,
                        FileShare.Write,
                        myStore);
```

Hope the above helps... if not check whether the Directory is really created...

**EDIT:**

Are you sure the `Exception` is thrown from the `catch-block` ? IF so, then there must have happened some `Exception` before that - what was that `Exception`?